# Session State and Application Pool

Tags: .net, session-state

I have a webserver, and my team have set the application pool for the web application to 3 for resilence and performance. However, we have stumbled upon a problem where part of the application is not fully working.

We believe the problem lies where this part of the application uses sessions, and we think that when the data is posted back it doesn't link back to the correct worker process.

However, I am not sure about this, or whether I should be using SessionState in the web.config. If I am right, should the mode be InProc, SessionState, or whatever? Should there be a timeout on the session?

Can someone please advise me?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use InProc in a multithreaded way (3 threads in the app pool) without guaranteeing that each request goes to the same thread.

InProc literally means in process, as in the memory of the current thread.

If you move to another storage method, say, to the database, then session can be shared across all instances of a given application.

I suggest reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx)

Comment: Could this work through an Oracle Database? If so is there an example?

Answer (score 0):

So you have broken your application into three parts on the same server, each running under its own application pool in IIS? I would challenge the assumptions behind doing this but that is really not your question.

I do not think you can do this and share session state using the out-of-the-box tools. It uses the site (metabase) path as part of the session state "key", so sessions from different sites do not collide.

But if you could do it, you would need to use one of the out-of-proc sessionState modes (StateServer or SQLServer).

I haven't tried the following, but they may help you.

Here is a link to a [Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Sharing_session_state.aspx) that describes modifying SQL Server Sessioning to group sites and share sessions.

Here is a link to an [ASP 101 article](http://www.asp101.com/articles/jayram/sharestate/default.asp) that describes one way to share sessions with child sites. Not sure if this would work in your case with different application pools.

EDIT:

Ah, a web garden. Yes, your worker processes don't share InProc session data. You need to use an external provider. The StateServer works fine. You'll need to enable the ASP.NET State Service on a server and update your web.config to use it. There are some things to consider with it:

- Is it running on a different server
  than IIS? Need to enable remote
  connections.
- Do you have multiple web
  servers? Need to define a machine
  key.
- Are you storing objects in
  session? Need to mark them
  serializable.

There are many resources online to help with this, here is an example [blog post](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2007/11/ASPNET-load-balancing-and-ASPNET-state-server-%28aspnet_state%29.aspx).

Comment: Not quite. This part of application has its own web.config as each part of the application was built as a project inside a solution in Visual Studio 2010. On IIS we gave this application its own website and app pool, and in the app pool we gave it 3 asp.net worker processes or web gards. If the app pool is set to default it is fine and works as expected, set it to 3 - it doesn't. I don't think using SQL Server is possible as the database we use is Oracle.